# Symmetric tree algorithm

Tags: java, database, algorithm, tree

**I need help solving this problem.** Only hints please

> Given a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (ie, symmetric around its center).
>   [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgr5f.png)

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public boolean isSymmetric(TreeNode root) {
        if((root == null) || (root.left == null && root.right == null)){return true;}

    }

    public boolean helper(TreeNode left, TreeNode right){


    }


}
```

The trouble I am having is somehow creating a recursive problem out of this. I am confused because as we branch out, how do I compare one back to the other using helper?

Can someone provide hints?

Answer (score 1):

Recursively call your helper method like following

```
if (left != null && right != null && left.key == right.key)
            return (helper(left.left, right.right)
                    && helper(left.right, right.left));
```

Note that,
we are checking whether the left of the left node and right of the right node is symmetric and right of the left node and left of the right node is symmetric. If both are symmetric then the main tree will be too.

Comment: So much for only hints... :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. If only root return true.
2. Else remove root and you will get two sub tress, compare the root with other sub tree. If they are same and have no sub tree return true. Else again remove the root and you will get the two sub tree. Follow the 2nd step again until you will find only one root node. If you find root node on one sub tree but null on other return false.

[image]

Comment: Ok, but on level 3, when the second children branch out, there are 4 nodes right? 2 on sub tree 1, 2 on sub tree 2? So how does the comparison work now?

Comment: I think you should use the recursion, so always you will have two sub trees and you just have to pop the root and compare it, I have updated the image and tried for level 3.